# Sublime 3 - removing extra spaces within an HTML tag

Tags: html, sublimetext2, html-email, sublimetext3, code-organization

I am still a newbie user of Sublime so there might be an easy way to do this.

I have an HTML where one HTML tag is forced into 2 lines. I possibly copied it from somewhere else and this just got stuck there. 
Here is an example:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
            align="center" width="100%"
            style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" class="deviceWidth">
```

After cellspacing a width a new line starts for no reason which makes the whole code hard to read.

So what I need is without going through the code and one buy one deleting the extra spaces, a way to delete these automatically and in bulk.

So in essence the force the above code to appear like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;" class="deviceWidth">
```

can you help me with this?

Any answer is appreciated!

Comment: use this website to do code beautify http://jsbeautifier.org/. Just paste all your code (ctrl+a) inside the text area and click the below button (Beautify Javascript/HTML)

Comment: great this does the trick. Although I was hoping there is an in-build functionality or there is a Sublime plug-in that does the same :)

Comment: try this https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify

Comment: brilliant. totally works. Sublime is getting better and better :)